# Instead of null print zero in awk

Tags: awk

I have a problem. This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100} # I do this script on 100 files, that is s why I use for loop
do
    sort -k2,2 -k1,1 eq9_x4_$index.ndx | 
    uniq -c             | 
    uniq -f2 -c         | 
    awk '
    ($1==1 && $2==4) {inner+=6} 
    ($1==2 && $2==1) {inner+=3; outer+=3} 
    ($1==2 && $2==2) {inner+=2; outer+=4} 
    ($1==3 && $2==1) {inner+=1; outer+=5} 
    ($1==4 && $2==1) {outer+=6} 
    END{print inner, outer}' >> inner_outer_water_bridges_x4.txt
done
```

It counts water bridges and print sum (inner and outer)
This is part of my output file and instead of this

```
9 15
2 16

8 10
4 14
 6
5 25
2 10
6
```

I want to have this

```
9 15
2 16
0 0
8 10
4 14
0 6
5 25
2 10
6 0
```

How to do this is there any good solution in awk?

Comment: Print `inner+0, outer+0`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: cast (empty) string to integer. Very nice idea.

Comment: @Cyrus Learnt it from the great Ed Morton of course :-)

Comment: Of course, you could just initialise your variables with `BEGIN{inner=outer=0}`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It was the same for me. When I came here, I only knew `awk '{print $1}' file`.

Comment: Cyrus & @MarkSetchell - Aw shucks you guys, stop it.... :-).

Comment: @Mark you can almost certainly do whatever it is you're trying to do with just one simple awk command rather than a shell loop running a sort and 2 uniqs and an awk. Post a new question with a couple of sample `eq9_x4_$index.ndx` input files and the expected output if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ternary operator try following. Couldn't test it since only code samples provided here.

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100} # I do this script on 100 files, that is s why I use for loop
do
    sort -k2,2 -k1,1 eq9_x4_$index.ndx | 
    uniq -c             | 
    uniq -f2 -c         | 
    awk '
    ($1==1 && $2==4) {inner+=6} 
    ($1==2 && $2==1) {inner+=3; outer+=3} 
    ($1==2 && $2==2) {inner+=2; outer+=4} 
    ($1==3 && $2==1) {inner+=1; outer+=5} 
    ($1==4 && $2==1) {outer+=6} 
    END{print (inner?inner:0), (outer?outer:0)}' >> inner_outer_water_bridges_x4.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing solely with integers you might harness `printf` following way

```
END{printf "%d %d\n", inner, outer}
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*