# Substarct bash variable as a name

Tags: bash, awk

This is my script

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' eq3_dgdg_1.ndx eq3_dgdg_2.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_2.ndx
for index in {3..5001} 
do
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' eq3_dgdg_$index.ndx eq4_dgdg_${index-1}.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_$index.ndx
done
```

In the first line I created eq4_dgdg_2.ndx
Then here

```
for index in {3..5001} 
do
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' eq3_dgdg_$index.ndx eq4_dgdg_${index-1}.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_$index.ndx
done
```

I want to use two files eq3_dgdg_3.ndx and eq4_dgdg_2.ndx, but I do something wrong and I don't know what.
Is this

```
eq4_dgdg_${index-1}.ndx
```

Will be

```
eq4_dgdg_2.ndx
```

when in my for loop I have 3 (first pass for loop)

Also if you have idea how to do that without bash for loop - using only awk tell me. Here I have advice [Instead using awk in for loop in bash through all files - do something only in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980443/instead-using-awk-in-for-loop-in-bash-through-all-files-do-something-only-in-a/66048733#66048733) but I want to write my output to another file not to the same

Comment: replace with `$((index-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem and not use a shell loop, instead of:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' eq3_dgdg_1.ndx eq3_dgdg_2.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_2.ndx
for index in {3..5001} 
do
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' eq3_dgdg_$index.ndx eq4_dgdg_${index-1}.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_$index.ndx
done
```

you'd write something like (untested since no sample input/output was provided in the question):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }
    FNR == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME
        sub(/3/,"4",out)
        delete b
        for (i in a) {
            b[i]
        }
        delete a
    }
    $0 in b {
        print
        print > out
        delete b[$0]
        a[$0]
    }
' eq3_dgdg_{1..5001}.ndx
```