# Delete lines with specific pattern name in the first column awk

Tags: awk

I want to delete all lines in which MGD is **not** between 676 and 900.
I wrote a script

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100} # I do this script on 100 files, that is why I use for loop
do
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "MGD" };
        {if ($2 >= 676 && $2 <= 900) print}' eq2_15_333_$index.ndx | tee eq3_15_333_$index.ndx
done
```

Input example

```
MGD816 SOL77
MGD71 SOL117
MGD7 SOL13194
MGD18 SOL235
MGD740 SOL340
MGD697 SOL396
MGD70 SOL9910
```

Expected output

```
MGD816 SOL77
MGD740 SOL340
MGD697 SOL396
```

I don't know what my script do something wrong, because I still have something which has MGD7 or MGD71, but MGD18 I haven't in my output.

Edit

I tested this script and it works perfectly

```
   awk '/^MGD/{val=substr($1,4);if(val+0 >= 676 && val+0 <= 900){print}}' new.txt | tee new2.txt
```

and I have output

```
MGD816 SOL77
MGD740 SOL340
MGD697 SOL396
```

Comment: As I always point out in your posts (but I'm trying to stop myself!) - you don't need a shell loop for this and it'd literally run orders of magnitude faster if you didn't.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for advice So how to do this example without for loop? Is it possible?

Comment: See our conversation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980078/problem-with-the-save-changes-in-the-same-file-with-awk#comment116656232_65980078 - nothing has changed.

Comment: @EdMorton I try again with my question. I hope now is ok? Thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980443/instead-using-awk-in-for-loop-in-bash-through-all-files-do-something-only-in-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples try following once. This is completely based on your shown attempt, since no samples were provided so its not tested, should work though.

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100}
do
   awk '/^MGD/{val=substr($1,4);if(val+0 >= 676 && val+0 <= 900){print}}' eq2_15_333_$index.ndx | tee eq3_15_333_$index.ndx
done
```

Comment: I edited the first post and try your script and test this script, but its not working.
I still have MGD between MGD7-9 and between MGD70-89 probably

Comment: @Mark, oh ok, my apologies, please try my edited code now?

Comment: Now it works perfect. Thank you so much. So I should "+0" to have properly output

Comment: @Mark, your welcome(yes +0 will do the trick), also you could revert your question to your actual question else it may confuse users(where you added my suggested command is not working there), cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain why your original i.e.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "MGD" }; {if ($2 >= 676 && $2 <= 900) print}'
```

did not work as excepted, you set `"MGD"` as `FS` thus AWK splitted only at `MGD` - if you do `awk 'BEGIN{FS="MGD"}{print $2}' file.txt` and content of `file.txt` is

```
MGD816 SOL77
MGD71 SOL117
MGD7 SOL13194
MGD18 SOL235
MGD740 SOL340
MGD697 SOL396
MGD70 SOL9910
```

output is

```
71 SOL117
7 SOL13194
18 SOL235
740 SOL340
697 SOL396
70 SOL9910
```

If you want `$2` to be first number you should specify `FS` which is `"MGD"` or spaces i.e.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="MGD|[[:space:]]+"}`...